# Adjusting the description about an equation in Latex

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I have to write the "Where" text about an equation as shown the given picture. The "Where" text appears to the left side which seems a little awkward as per the standards. Please suggest me, how can I move it below the equation or other standard options.

[image]

**My code:**

```
\begin{gather}
\text{spatial, } d_p(s^i,n^{jk}) = \sqrt{           (   s_x^i - n_x^{jk}    )^2         } \\
\text{and color distance component, } d_c(s^i,n^{jk}) = \sqrt{          (   s_L^i - n_L^{jk}    )^2 }
\end{gather}

$
\text{Where,}\\
\text{$\mathit{s^i = }$ the center of $\mathit{i^{th}}$ graph, }\\
\text{$\mathit{n^{jk} = }$ the $\mathit{j^{th}}$ node of $\mathit{k^{th}}$ graph}
$
```

Comment: don't leave a blank line after `gather` (`where`... is part of the same paragraph) and don't put `$` around it, it's not math, so then you don't need the `\text`) that will reduce some of the vertical space most likely, but otherwise that would be the setting I would expect.

Comment: don't use `\mathit{s^i = }` that makes the s and i come from a different font to that used in the main equation. `\mathit` uses the _text_ italic font not math italic.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Which one should I use instead of '\mathit{}'. I can't understand the suitable option for me.

Comment: just `$s^i={}$` you do not want to change fonts here. (the `{}` is needed to get the correct space around `=`)

Comment: Related question that could be adjusted to your needs: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244575/create-itemize-like-command

Comment: I would not write `=` in the text part. `=` is a mathematical relationship symbol belonging in equations. Just write `is`.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \text{Spatial,}\quad d_p(s^i,n^{jk}) & = √{(s_x^{\vphantom{j}i} - n_x^{jk})^2} \\ %
  \text{and color distance component,}\quad
  d_c(s^i,n^{jk}) & = √{(s_L^i - n_L^{\smash jk})^2 } \\[-1ex] % with smashed j
  \intertext{where\enspace \begin{tabular}[t]{|@{\ }>{$}r<{={} $}@{}l}
  s^i & the center of $i$th graph,\tabularnewline
  n^{jk} & the $j$-th node of $k$\textsuperscript{th} graph.
  \end{tabular}\vskip-1.5\baselineskip}%
  \notag
\end{align} %
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this?

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    \blindtext Something spatial,   
    \begin{align}
    d_p(s^i,n^{jk}) &= \sqrt{(s_x^{\vphantom{j}i} - n_x^{jk})^2} \\ % with phantom j
    \intertext{and color distance component,}
    d_c(s^i,n^{jk}) &= \sqrt{(s_L^i - n_L^{\smash jk})^2 }\\ % with smashed j
    \shortintertext{where}
    s^i &=  \text{the center of $i$th graph,}\notag\\
    n^{jk} &=  \text{the $j$-th node of $k$\textsuperscript{th} graph.}\notag
    \end{align}
    or as Manuel suggests:
    \begin{align*}
        s^i &=  \text{the center of $i$th graph,}\\
        n^{jk} &=  \text{the $j$-th node of $k$\textsuperscript{th} graph.}
    \end{align*}
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

I have added three different versions for the "th". Of course, you should chose one.

[image]

Comment: When I try to use it, I am getting the confliction error because I have already defined \usepackage{amsmath}.

Comment: @skm just replace `amsmath` by `mathtools`. This should be safe.

Comment: I wouldn't align them all. The last two are not on the “same level” as the first two lines, and I see no reason for their alignment. I would probably use `{align}` with `\intertext` for the first two lines, then `where \[ \begin{aligned} .. \end{aligned} \]`.

Comment: @Manuel Thanks for the idea. I added that. Some reason why to use `\[\begin{aligned}...` instead of `\begin{align*}...`? I noticed a minimal difference in horizontal position which I would not have expected.

Comment: With `\[\!\begin{aligned} .. \end{aligned}\]` (notice the `\!` which I forgot, due to some —unnecessary— space added by the environment) you get the spacing of `\[ .. \]` which is tighter if the line before is short (in this case, just “where”). In any case, the thing is that I wouldn't align the four lines, the first two and the last two only.

Comment: @Manuel Thanks, got that. Yes, I understood your last point. Put both in my example. May the OP decide. @ skm, if you take the last approach, your two main equations will be set a bit more to the right than they are in my screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

I adapted my recent answer at [Create itemize-like command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244575/create-itemize-like-command/244577#244577), and actually prefer its look to what the OP asks here.  Nonetheless, I have adapted it to look more in a manner the OP has specified.  The default `\leftmargin` is `.4\textwidth`, but that can be overridden with an optional length argument to the `explanation` environment.

Other changes from the referenced answer, in addition to the default left margin: I use `=` instead of `---`; I place "where" on its own separate line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,amsmath}
\let\svitem\item
\newenvironment{explanation}[1][.4\textwidth]
{\newcommand\itemB[1][]{\svitem[##1${}={}$]}%
 \let\item\itemB%
 where
 \begin{list}{}{\leftmargin=#1\labelwidth=\dimexpr1in+#1\relax%
                \itemsep=0pt\parsep=0pt\labelsep=0pt}%
}
{\end{list}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
And now for my equation.
\begin{gather}
\text{spatial, } d_p(s^i,n^{jk}) = \sqrt{           (   s_x^i - n_x^{jk}    )^2         } \\
\text{and color distance component, } d_c(s^i,n^{jk}) = \sqrt{          (   s_L^i - n_L^{jk}    )^2 }
\end{gather}
\begin{explanation}
    \item[$s^i$] the center of $\mathit{i^{th}}$ graph,
    \item[$n^{jk}$] the $\mathit{j^{th}}$ node of $\mathit{k^{th}}$ graph
\end{explanation}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]