# Create itemize-like command

Tags: macros

Can I somehow create a new command with this functionality:

```
{\tabcolsep=0mm
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{r@{\,---\,}X}
    where $P$ & power of transmitter, dB;\\
    $G_a$ & Gaining, dBi;\\
    $\eta$ & Energy conversion efficiency, dB.\\
\end{tabularx}}
```

as an itemize-like command:

```
\begin{explanation}
    \item[$P$] power of transmitter, dB;
    \item[$G_a$] Gaining, dBi;
    \item[$\eta$]  Energy conversion efficiency, dB.
\end{explanation}
```

and with this result:

[image]

Comment: Do you want it to star at the same line? (It's probably not going to look good.)

Comment: It's ok. It can be many same type variables on one place, as a_0, a_1, a_n and dash must be in one line.

Comment: Style note: it would be clearer to replace the dash with text: `where $P$~is the power of the transmitter`, for example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

EDITED to provide optional value of `\leftmargin` for the "explanation."

REVISED to provide hanging indent by using `\leftmargin`, rather than `\itemindent`.  Also, I removed the space following the em-dash.
In addition, I extended `\labelwidth` to `\leftmargin+1in`, which will mean if the `\leftindent` (optional argument) is too small, the labels will extend into the left margin.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\let\svitem\item
\newenvironment{explanation}[1][6em]
{\newcommand\itemA[1][]{\svitem[where ##1---]\let\item\itemB}%
 \newcommand\itemB[1][]{\svitem[##1---]}%
 \let\item\itemA%
 \begin{list}{}{\leftmargin=#1\labelwidth=\dimexpr1in+#1\relax%
                \itemsep=0pt\parsep=0pt\labelsep=0pt}%
}
{\end{list}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\[
P = P(G_n,\eta)
\]
\begin{explanation}[7em]
    \item[$P$] power of transmitter, dB;
    \item[$G_a$] Gaining, dBi;
    \item[$\eta$]  Energy conversion efficiency, dB. And now I include extra explanation 
  to run over a single line.
\end{explanation}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh i am sorry, i testing your solution and recall that i didn't mention that if definition transiting on new line, then it must start right under first letter of definition, like in table. Exactly that is why i used tabularx.

Comment: @JolyRojer I am not sure I understand what you mean.  Are you talking about if a definition extends to multiple lines in an explanation?

Comment: @JolyRojer  Fixed.  Please see revision.