# indentation within the text

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, indentation

While preparing a report, I want to write the text (below the equations) similar to attached figure. I tried using `\begin{align}`,`\,` commands (even after knowing that the align command is using for equations). But it won't worked the way I need. Any solution, please? [image]

Comment: Perhaps this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244575/create-itemize-like-command?lq=1 gives what you want.

Comment: Does the image you posted show the output you wish to obtain, or the output of your current solution?  And in the latter case, what output would you prefer?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes thank you for the suggestion. I tried to create the environment `{explanation}` in my project's class file. But it need `{lipsum}` package and I won't found it. Is there any other solution with the packages  that I am having: `\usepackage{natbib}\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}`

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti, the image is what I need in my output and I am unable to find the way to express it in my code. Any suggestion?

Comment: @vis54132: At least provide us with something we can copy-and-paste and use as a foundation. We can then compare your foundational code and see how that compares to the image in order to deduce exactly what you want. It will not only speed up getting you answers, but also make your question more clear and help future visitors as well. A win-win, all around.

Comment: this looks like a good candidate for the `tabbing` environment -- set up notional "tab stops" at specified intervals, which are then used essentially like tabs would be used on a typewriter.  (best results when nothing in the affected block requires more than a single line.)

Comment: `lipsum` is just a package that provides filler text.  It is not needed for the solution, but I used it so as to demonstrate my answer in the context of other text.  Just remove `\usepackage{lipsum}` and then replace all references to `\lipsum[]` in the example with text like `blah blah blah`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the OP was having issues with my referenced answer, I provide this package-free alternative to help move him/her along.

Additionally, this alternative uses **left-aligned** labels of width `\mylabelwidth`, and the word "with" instead of "where".

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\mylabelwidth{.5cm}
\let\svitem\item
\def\mymkbox#1{\makebox[\mylabelwidth][l]{#1}}
\newenvironment{explanation}[1][6em]
{\newcommand\itemA[1][]{\svitem[with \mymkbox{##1}\quad]\let\item\itemB}%
 \newcommand\itemB[1][]{\svitem[\mymkbox{##1}\quad]}%
 \let\item\itemA%
 \begin{list}{}{\leftmargin=#1\labelwidth=\dimexpr1in+#1\relax%
                \itemsep=0pt\parsep=0pt\labelsep=0pt}%
}
{\end{list}}
\begin{document}
blah bla bla blah bla bla blah bla bla blah bla bla blah bla bla blah bla bla 
blah bla bla blah bla bla blah bla bla blah bla bla blah bla bla blah bla bla 
blah bla bla blah bla bla blah bla bla blah bla bla blah bla bla blah bla bla 
blah bla bla blah bla bla blah bla bla blah bla bla blah bla bla blah bla bla 
\[
P = P(G_n,\eta)
\]
\begin{explanation}[8em]
    \item[$P$] power of transmitter, dB;
    \item[$G_a$] Gaining, dBi;
    \item[$\eta$]  Energy conversion efficiency, dB. And now I include extra explanation 
  to run over a single line.
\end{explanation}
blah bla bla blah bla bla blah bla bla blah bla bla blah bla bla blah bla bla 
blah bla bla blah bla bla blah bla bla blah bla bla blah bla bla blah bla bla 
blah bla bla blah bla bla blah bla bla blah bla bla blah bla bla blah bla bla 
blah bla bla blah bla bla blah bla bla blah bla bla blah bla bla blah bla bla 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Steven B. Segletes, with your previous comment, I tried to solve the code. And it worked. Still your above answer provides more details to understand the developed `{explanation}` environment thoroughly. Thank you. :-)